# LM27762: 200 mV difference between positive and negative

Tags: operational-amplifier, ldo, charge-pump

I'm trying to figure out why there is 200 mV difference between positive and negative voltage on [LM27762](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm27762.pdf) (measured these values at op-amp pins). I used a schematic from their datasheet and everything was done according to their recommendations (layout, parts). Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Everything is meaningless without a schematic.

Comment: Everything is meaningless without a data sheet.

Comment: How much difference you expect and why? The rails mean power supply rails to me, I'd expect more as the opamp does not work with 200mV, but maybe you don't mean the supply rails.

Comment: Uploaded a schematic used for LM27762

Comment: @Justme 200mV in audio application is too much, you can even hear a difference between left/right channels

Comment: The LM27762 isn't an op-amp. What op-amp? Where on schematic?

Comment: @Andyaka yeah but it's a power supply for op-amp in my case (read the post again)

Comment: Nobody is a mind-reader. Nobody knows what pins you talk about. Nobody knows whether you are saying there is a literal difference of 200 mV or a magnitude difference. Too much information missing.

Answer (score 2):

The reference voltages are slightly different in magnitude and there are tolerances. Worst case is -1.238 vs. +1.182 (at 25°C). Then there are tolerances on the resistors- you have specified 5% resistors.

Assuming you are referring to |Out+|-|Out-|, 200mV is within spec.

The exact *nominal* voltages are +5.057 and -5.141

This should make no difference unless your amplifier is clipping, and even then not much.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really using 5% resistors on the feedback pins you can expect a worst-case absolute<sup>1</sup> difference of over 860 mV between the positive and negative outputs.<sup>2</sup>

You might want to replace one of the resistors on each feedback divider with a trimpot so that you can fine-tune the feedback voltages.

---

<sup>1</sup> i.e. ignoring the signs and just taking each output's distance from 0 volts.

<sup>2</sup> Depending on the exact values of the resistors the output voltages will vary.  Using the 5% 56k Ω and 180k Ω resistors specified in the schematic and assuming that the LM27762's internal voltage references are exact:

**Equations** 
\$V_{out+} = 1.2 V × \frac{R_1 + R_2}{R_2}\$ 
\$V_{out-} = –1.22 V × \frac{R_3 + R_4}{R_4}\$

**Ideal case** 
\$R_1=R_3=180kΩ\$ 
\$R_2=R_4=56kΩ\$ 

\$V_{out+} = 5.0571428571 V\$ 
\$V_{out-} = -5.1414285714 V\$ 

\$abs(V_{out-}) - V_{out+} = 0.0842857143 V\$

**Worst case** 
\$R_1=58.8kΩ \ \ \ \scriptsize{\text{(105% of specified value)}}\$ 
\$R_2=171kΩ \ \ \ \ \scriptsize{\text{(95% of specified value)}}\$ 
\$R_3=53.2kΩ \ \ \ \scriptsize{\text{(95% of specified value)}}\$ 
\$R_4=189kΩ \ \ \ \ \scriptsize{\text{(105% of specified value)}}\$ 

\$V_{out+} = 4.6897959184 V\$ 
\$V_{out-} = -5.5542105263 V\$ 

\$abs(V_{out-}) - V_{out+} = 0.8644146079 V\$

Comment: I'm actually using 1% resistors for 180K and 56K, that's a mistake in a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can hear any difference if positive supply and negative supply differs by 200mV so it is irrelevant.

If you do hear a difference, the problem is somewhere else, such as the signal level being too strong and not leaving enough margin for power supply tolerances.

As for why the difference, even in ideal case, when using identical feedback resistor values for positive and negative regulators, there would be about 100mV of difference, because the regulators have different feedback reference values (1.2V vs -1.22V). The reference voltages themselves have about 1.5% tolerance. Then add resistor tolerance of 5%. Simply the 180k resistor being 5% too high causes about 200mV of deviation from ideal value.